# Python string matching with Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, string-matching, string-comparison, fuzzywuzzy

I have a spark dataframe

```
id  | city  | fruit | quantity
-------------------------
0   |  CA   | apple | 300
1   |  CA   | appel | 100
2   |  CA   | orange| 20
3   |  CA   | berry | 10
```

I want to get rows where fruits are `apple` or `orange`. So I use Spark SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fruit LIKE '%apple%' OR fruit LIKE '%orange%';
```

It returns

```
id  | city  | fruit | quantity
-------------------------
0   |  CA   | apple | 300
2   |  CA   | orange| 20
```

But it is supposed to return

```
id  | city  | fruit | quantity
-------------------------
0   |  CA   | apple | 300
1   |  CA   | appel | 100
2   |  CA   | orange| 20
```

as row 1 is just a misspelling.

So I plan on using `fuzzywuzzy` for string matching.
I know that

```
import fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

print(fuzz.partial_ratio('apple', 'apple')) -> 100
print(fuzz.partial_ratio('apple', 'appel')) -> 83
```

But am not sure how to apply this to a column in dataframe to get relevant rows

Comment: You can register the fuzzywuzzy function as a udf.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are interested in implementing fuzzy matching as a filter, you must first decide on a threshold of how similar you would like the matches.

#### Approach 1

For your `fuzzywuzzy` import this could be `80` for the purpose of this demonstration (adjust based on your needs). You could then implement a udf to apply your imported fuzzy logic code eg

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

F.udf(T.BooleanType())
def is_fuzzy_match(field_value,search_value, threshold=80):
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
    return fuzz.partial_ratio(field_value, search_value) > threshold
```

Then apply your udf as a filter on your dataframe

```py
df = (
    df.where(
          is_fuzzy_match(F.col("fruit"),F.lit("apple"))  | 
          is_fuzzy_match(F.col("fruit"),F.lit("orange"))  
    )
)
```

#### Approach 2 : Recommended

However, udfs can be expensive when executed on spark and spark has already implemented the [`levenshtein`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.levenshtein.html) function which is also useful here. You may start reading more about how the [levenshtein distance accomplishes fuzzy matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) .

With this approach your code code look like using a threshold of `3` below

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.where(
    (
        F.levenshtein(
            F.col("fruit"),
            F.lit("apple")
        ) < 3
     ) |
     (
        F.levenshtein(
            F.col("fruit"),
            F.lit("orange")
        ) < 3
     ) 
)

df.show()
```

```
+---+----+------+--------+
| id|city| fruit|quantity|
+---+----+------+--------+
|  0|  CA| apple|     300|
|  1|  CA| appel|     100|
|  2|  CA|orange|      20|
+---+----+------+--------+
```

For debugging purposes the result of the levenshtein has been included below

```py
df.withColumn("diff",
    F.levenshtein(
        F.col("fruit"),
        F.lit("apple")
    )
).show()
```

```
+---+----+------+--------+----+
| id|city| fruit|quantity|diff|
+---+----+------+--------+----+
|  0|  CA| apple|     300|   0|
|  1|  CA| appel|     100|   2|
|  2|  CA|orange|      20|   5|
|  3|  CA| berry|      10|   5|
+---+----+------+--------+----+
```

### Update 1

In response to additional sample data provided by Op in comments:

> If I have a fruit like kashmir apple and want it to match with apple

#### Approach 3

You could try the following approach and adjust the threshold as desired.

Since you are interested in matching the possibility of a misspelled fruit throughout the text, you could attempt to apply the levenshtein to every piece throughout the fruit name. The functions below (not udfs but for readability simplifies the application of the task ) implement this approach. `matches_fruit_ratio` attempts to determine how much of a match is found while `matches_fruit` determines the maximum `matches_fruit_ratio` on every piece of the fruit name split by a space.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def matches_fruit_ratio(fruit_column,fruit_search,threshold=0.3):
    return (F.length(fruit_column) - F.levenshtein(
        fruit_column,
        F.lit(fruit_search)
    )) / F.length(fruit_column) 

def matches_fruit(fruit_column,fruit_search,threshold=0.6):
    return F.array_max(F.transform(
        F.split(fruit_column," "),
        lambda fruit_piece : matches_fruit_ratio(fruit_piece,fruit_search)
    )) >= threshold
```

This can be used as follows:

```py
df = df.where(
    
    matches_fruit(
        F.col("fruit"),
        "apple"
    ) | matches_fruit(
        F.col("fruit"),
        "orange"
    )
)
df.show()
```

```
+---+----+-------------+--------+
| id|city|        fruit|quantity|
+---+----+-------------+--------+
|  0|  CA|        apple|     300|
|  1|  CA|        appel|     100|
|  2|  CA|       orange|      20|
|  4|  CA|  apply berry|       3|
|  5|  CA|  apple berry|       1|
|  6|  CA|kashmir apple|       5|
|  7|  CA|kashmir appel|       8|
+---+----+-------------+--------+
```

For debugging purposes, I have added additional sample data and output columns for the different components of each function while demonstrating how this function may be used

```py
df.withColumn("length",
    F.length(
        "fruit"
    )
).withColumn("levenshtein",
    F.levenshtein(
        F.col("fruit"),
        F.lit("apple")
    )
).withColumn("length - levenshtein",
    F.length(
        "fruit"
    ) - F.levenshtein(
        F.col("fruit"),
        F.lit("apple")
    )
).withColumn(
    "matches_fruit_ratio",
    matches_fruit_ratio(
        F.col("fruit"),
        "apple"
    )
).withColumn(
    "matches_fruit_values_before_threshold",
    F.array_max(F.transform(
        F.split("fruit"," "),
        lambda fruit_piece : matches_fruit_ratio(fruit_piece,"apple")
    ))
).withColumn(
    "matches_fruit",
    matches_fruit(
        F.col("fruit"),
        "apple"
    )
).show()
```

```
+---+----+-------------+--------+------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
| id|city|        fruit|quantity|length|levenshtein|length - levenshtein|matches_fruit_ratio|matches_fruit_values_before_threshold|matches_fruit|
+---+----+-------------+--------+------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
|  0|  CA|        apple|     300|     5|          0|                   5|                1.0|                                  1.0|         true|
|  1|  CA|        appel|     100|     5|          2|                   3|                0.6|                                  0.6|         true|
|  2|  CA|       orange|      20|     6|          5|                   1|0.16666666666666666|                  0.16666666666666666|        false|
|  3|  CA|        berry|      10|     5|          5|                   0|                0.0|                                  0.0|        false|
|  4|  CA|  apply berry|       3|    11|          6|                   5|0.45454545454545453|                                  0.8|         true|
|  5|  CA|  apple berry|       1|    11|          6|                   5|0.45454545454545453|                                  1.0|         true|
|  6|  CA|kashmir apple|       5|    13|          8|                   5|0.38461538461538464|                                  1.0|         true|
|  7|  CA|kashmir appel|       8|    13|         10|                   3|0.23076923076923078|                                  0.6|         true|
+---+----+-------------+--------+------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: If I have a fruit like kashmir apple and want it to match with apple. If I use the levenshtein distance it would show the distance as 8, that's why I want to use fuzz.partial_ratio

Comment: @JohnConstantine Thanks for sharing the additional sample that provides a better idea of your use case. You may try the udf mentioned in the answer or implement the `partial_ratio` in spark as described [here](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/master/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py). I've updated the answer with another approach which may prove more useful. Let me know if this works for you.